# SQL Server 2019 and TDE

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption, sql-server-2019

We are about to move away from SQL 2008R2 to a much newer version. We upgraded to the Enterprise Edition of 2008R2 just for TDE, but I was just browsing here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15 and it appears to say that SS2019 includes TDE in the Standard Edition (the 2017 and older pages confirm it’s Enterprise Edition only).

Is this a typo or did I miss the memo and my life just got a LOT cheaper?

Comment: Correct: Your life got cheaper.... Assuming you're not using other Enterprise Features, like AGs or online index operations